# Can't run Hyper-V, but all hardware indicate that it's good to go

Tags: windows-8.1, bios, hyper-v

I'm trying to get my Hyper-V to work on my home computer. As I see it, all my hardware supports Virtualization and the software SecurAble is saying Good to go. Yes in Hardware D.E.P. and Yes to Hardware Virtualization.

My Motherboard is GA-Z68X-UD3H-B3 and my CPU is Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600K CPU @ 3.40GHz (8 CPUs), ~3.7GHz. BIOS is updated and factory defaults after update. 
Virtualization is enabled in the BIOS too.

I found this post about my motherboard: [Does VT-d need hardware support (besides the CPU)?](https://superuser.com/questions/609228/does-vt-d-need-hardware-support-besides-the-cpu/639174#639174)
And as I read it, I can run Hyper-V. But when I start my virtual machine I get the message:

> Virtual Machine 'Name os Hyper-V machine' could not be started because the hypervisor is not running.

The message indicates that I haven't enabled all settings for virtualization, but I can't see what that is now, and therefor asking for help here :-)

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit...
My apologizes for forgetting that info :-)

Comment: There are several spelling mistakes that make this question extremely hard to read...all facts should be in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a long time looking at this issue, and not being able to find a solution for it, I found a solution for the issue and it solved my problem.

**Source for solution:** http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2010/01/19/hyper-v-virtual-machines-do-not-start-after-using-startup-repair.aspx

> **Title:** Hyper-V virtual machines do not start after using Startup Repair
>
> Over the weekend, I attempted to reconfigure some of the drives in my Hyper-V server at home.  Note that I said *attempted*.  I ran into hardware issues and ended up having to revert back to my old  configuration - but somehow in all of this – I broke my system disk.
>
> Specifically it would not boot any more.
>
> This did not phase me because I knew that the excellent startup repair tool in Windows would soon  have me up and running – which it did.
>
> But I was surprised to find that when my system did finally boot – none of my virtual machines  started up.  When I tried to start the virtual machines manually, I was informed that the hypervisor was not running.
>
> After scratching my head for a moment, I realized what had happened.  Startup repair had rebuilt my boot configuration data store to get my system up and running.  But it did not know that Hyper-V needs to have some specific settings enabled in the boot configuration data store in order to start the hypervisor.
>
> I quickly opened an administrative command prompt and ran the following command:
>
> **bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto**
>
> After that I rebooted the system and successfully started my virtual machines.
>
> Cheers, 
>   Ben

The solution was this command line below and a computer restart:

Comment: Worked for me. FYI, another symptom for me was if I tried to manually start the "HV Host Service" it would fail with the (not so) helpful error "A device attached to the system is not functioning."

Comment: Thank you very much. Not for the solution only, but for the explanation. I saw similar answers but did not feel confident just running a command I did not understand. Wasted 4 hours trying to fix this mess up. Always fun after IT pushes updates

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching, I found out that I did not had a hypervisor component installed.

After checking it and rebooting virtual machine works without problems!

[image: hypervisor not installed]

Answer (score -1):

There are [two settings](http://blogs.technet.com/b/iftekhar/archive/2010/08/09/enable-hardware-settings-in-bios-to-run-hyper-v.aspx) for ensure that Hyper-V runs with Intel chips:

1. Intel VT-d is disabled
2. "Trusted Execution" is disabled ***or*** "Execute Disable" is enabled

The second one is tricky because it's confusing to EVERYONE. It seems to be different on every motherboard, and the double-negative of "enable the disable" doesn't help at all!

Once these are set properly, you need to [fully power down](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/194.hyper-v-2008-troubleshooting-event-id-3112-the-virtual-machine-could-not-be-started-because-the-hypervisor-is-not-running.aspx) the machine to ensure that the new settings take effect. New "quick reboot" features do not necessarily mean that Windows 8 reboots from a fully powered-down state which is necessary for this change.

The same link above says that the next step is to check your [Boot Configuration Data](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721886(WS.10).aspx) store to ensure that Hyper-V is actually set to start when the OS starts, but most problems are getting the BIOS/UEFI settings right.

The best resource I've found is [this 5-minute video](http://www.msn.com/en-us/video/watch/hypervisor-is-not-running-error-how-to-fix/vi-25d07f2e-b2e0-4c0c-b456-79b08bfe58be) in which he walks you through all the detail. (I would type it all out, but that would be plagiarizing)

In your particular situation, these would be my troubleshooting steps:

1. Fully power down the PC, start the PC and see if I can start the VM based on my previous changes
2. If that fails, go to the BIOS/UEFI and change the Trusted Execution/Execute Disable option from whatever it is to the other option (no to yes, yes to no), wait for the machine to boot, then repeat step 1
3. Check the BCD (which is beyond my knowledge, but can be researched)