# How to tell if MacBook supports VT-d?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, macbook, macbook-air, vt-d

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on MacBookAir6,2 with [Core-i7-4650U](https://ark.intel.com/products/75114/Intel-Core-i7-4650U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_30-GHz#infosectionadvancedtechnologies-scrollpane) CPU and trying to enable VT-d/IOMMU so that I could passthrough hardware to virtual machines (QEMU/KVM). According to the CPU spec, VT-d is supported.

So I added `intel_iommu=on` to the GRUB config as instructed [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/633183/how-do-i-enable-kvm-device-passthrough-in-linux). This caused boot failure with messages like this:

```
DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 2
DMAR: DMAR:[DMA Write] Request device [04:00.1] fault addr fffe00
```

A possible fix to that is suggested [here](https://centoros.wordpress.com/2015/07/22/iommu-dmar-fault/): to replace `intel_iommu=on` with `intel_iommu=pt`. This fixes the host boot process, however, trying to start a KVM machine with a PCI device added to it still results in "*Error starting domain: unsupported configuration: host doesn't support passthrough of host PCI devices*".

Further googling on that DMAR errors caused by `intel_iommu=on` resulted in the suspicion that the hardware as a body might not actually support VT-d, even though the CPU on its own does. I found [this page](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/boards-and-kits/desktop-boards/000005758.html) telling which Intel chipsets support VT-d, but I cannot find what chipset my MacBook has, if any. [This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/609228/does-vt-d-need-hardware-support-besides-the-cpu) hints that in my case VT-d would be wholly provided by the CPU only, but still to way to know it for sure.

So, how do I tell for sure if a MacBook Air supports VT-d, before trying to enable/troubleshoot it in Ubuntu?

UPDATE

I just confirmed that VT-d works on my MacBook Air. PCI passthrough worked on CentOS 7 with `intel_iommu=on`; even though the same boot errors as with Ubuntu showed up, the system booted fine.